# How to save checkboxes checkeds state after close modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've a modal with multiple checkboxes. It's like a modal filter...

So, If I checked the checkbox, close the modal and open it again, the checkbox that I clicked must be appears checked. (Here, I really don't know how to do it :/)

If I checked the checkbox and click in the "clean filter" `button`, all checbkoxes must be uncheckeds. (Here, I've a method that do it, but not works :/)

Someone can help me?? How can I do it?

I uploaded my code at codesandbox to see how it works: [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fhli3)

My structure:

```
<button onClick={this.toggleDrawer(true)}>OPEN MENU</button>
<SwipeableDrawer
  anchor="top"
  open={this.state.top}
  onClose={this.toggleDrawer(false)}
  onOpen={this.toggleDrawer(true)}
>
  <div style={{ padding: "15px" }}>
    {data.map(element => {
      return (
        <div key={element.Name}>
          <p>{element.Name}</p>
          {element.Cont.map(item => {
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={item.id}
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={e => this.onChangeBox(e, item.id)}
                    checked={this.state.checkboxArray[item.id]}
                    iditem={item.id}
                  />
                }
                label={item.contName}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>

  <div style={{ display: "flex", padding: "15px" }}>
    <div onClick={this.toggleDrawer(false)}>
      <button
        style={{
          background: "red",
          color: "white",
          padding: "9px"
        }}
      >
        CLOSE
      </button>
    </div>

    <div onClick={this.unChecked}>
      <button
        style={{
          background: "blue",
          color: "white",
          padding: "9px"
        }}
      >
        CLEAN ITENS
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</SwipeableDrawer>
```

Here is my methods to open/close modal, check checkboxes itens and uncheck them:

```
  toggleDrawer = open => event => {
    console.log("clicou");
    if (
      event &&
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ top: open });
  };

  onChangeBox = (event, iditem) => {
    this.handleCheckbox(event.target.checked, iditem);
    let checkBoxCurrentState = this.state.checkboxArray;
    checkBoxCurrentState[iditem] = !checkBoxCurrentState[iditem];
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: checkBoxCurrentState
    });
  };

  unChecked = () => {
    let resetArray = new Array(data.length).fill(false);
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: resetArray
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi Zkk see my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to jump straight to the solution see the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rcs5p

Below, I'll be explaining all the updates I made.

Let's try to centralize some of your code. Instead of directly mapping off the`data` array you have at the top of your sandbox, let's store that array in your state.

```
class MenuCheckbox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    drawerOpen: false,
    data: data
  };
....
```

Then we'll iterate off the state array to render the checkboxes in your drawer. The reason for this is to have a updated, localized reference of the data anytime we make changes:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDrawer(true)}>OPEN MENU</button>
        <SwipeableDrawer
          anchor="top"
          open={this.state.drawerOpen}
          onClose={this.toggleDrawer(false)}
        >
```

Great now let's look at the data array. To make things easier on ourselves, we should be giving each item a `checked` property. This will help keep track of the items that should be checked/unchecked when toggling the modal. It's cleaner and more explicitly this way.

Example to repeat for all items in data array:

```
  {
    Name: "Item 1",
    Cont: [
      {
        id: 1,
        contName: "Name 1",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        contName: "Name 2",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        contName: "Name 3",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
```

Cool now that our data-structure is setup nicely. We can write some clean logic to update the checkboxes. Looking at the array, we have a set of items `{}` (Level 1), where each item has its own inner array `[]` called `Cont` (Level 2), which stores our checkbox statuses.

So naturally, to create a function that can target the right checkbox, we need a minimum of 2 arguments, an index from the outer set of items and the index of the inner `Cont` item. Upon clicking a checkbox we will trigger this:

```
  onChangeBox = (dataIndex, contIndex) => {
    //turns our array into a string, then parses it back to an array. This is the best way to do a deep clone
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));

    data[dataIndex].Cont[contIndex].checked = !data[dataIndex].Cont[contIndex]
      .checked;

    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  };
```

Within the function, first we clone the array to avoid any indirect state-mutation. Then using that new array, we locate the checkbox that was selected and simply set the `checked` property to be the opposite of what it currently is. Finally, we update our state array with that new data.

This will work for both checking and unchecking.

Within the rendering logic for these checkboxes, we can use the second argument of `.map()` to pass in the indexes of the corresponding items. We can pass in the outer-index through the first `.map()` and the inner-index via the inner `.map()` of each cont Item.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDrawer(true)}>OPEN MENU</button>
        <SwipeableDrawer
          anchor="top"
          open={this.state.drawerOpen}
          onClose={this.toggleDrawer(false)}
        >
          <div style={{ padding: "15px" }}>
            {this.state.data.map((item, elementIndex) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.Name}>
                  <p>{item.Name}</p>
                  {item.Cont.map((contItem, contIndex) => {
                    return (
                      <FormControlLabel
                        key={contItem.id}
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            onChange={() =>
                              this.onChangeBox(elementIndex, contIndex)
                            }
                            checked={contItem.checked}
                            iditem={contItem.id}
                          />
                        }
                        label={contItem.contName}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
```

Finally to clear the checkboxes, we just need a function that will create a brand new array of items/checkboxes, where all the `contItem` checked-values are set to false. So we'll be using a `.map()` and a nested `.map()`.

```
  unChecked = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const updatedData = data.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        Cont: item.Cont.map(contItem => {
          return {
            ...contItem,
            checked: false
          };
        })
      };
    });

    this.setState({ data: updatedData });
  };
```

That's pretty much all of it. Hope this was helpful to you!

Comment: I was think something like that, but I didn't know how to turn into code. Now it's better to undestand, thank you so much for your help Christopher!

Answer (score 0):

**Note the change to your data.**

This should get you started.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-4z6os